# Can't edit my site using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I've a wsp file deployed on a site. The problem is that when the solution feature is activated, I'm not able to edit in Sharepoint Designer. Do you have any solution to this problem?  Please help me out.

Comment: What is the WSP solution?  Is it a custom solution you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

To help you, we need information about that wsp you deployed. Please tell us what exactly prevents you from editing the page.

Please have a look to your Sharepoint logs for the time you activated the feature and the time you tried to edit the page. Let us know what you found in there and we can surly assist you finding the cause.